# Mocking java objects gives class cast exceptions

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a interface `fly` and a class `duck` which implements `fly`.

```
interface Fly {
  getWingSize();   
}

public class Duck implements Fly {
  @Override
  int getWingSize(){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

In my controller class, when I try to use the following:

```
Fly flyAnimal = Animal.getFlyingAnimal();
((Duck) flyAnimal).getWingSize();
```

It works fine, however in my junit, it gives a class cast exception. I am using powermockito.

Comment: Please post a complete example and a full stack trace.

Comment: You should be using capitalized names for your classes, e.g. `interface Fly`.

Comment: yes, i am using capitalized names. i cant use the code on stackoverflow, hence i had to make up a code that was somewhat similar to what I am dealing with

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are casting to concrete class (duck). In general, you would mock interfaces. Your test case might have mocked interface fly.

It should work fine if you replace `((duck) fly).getWingSize();` with `fly.getWingSize();`

Comment: I am having issues with my junit, i am using mockito

Comment: please post your test case.

Comment: Duck duckAnimal = PowerMockito.mock(duck.class);         PowerMockito.when(duckAnimal. getWingSize()).thenReturn(1);

Comment: @mistack305 instead of making random stuff up paste by editing your question a real replicatble problem. There is no casting going on here in what you have posted. You can not get the exception you are saying you are getting.